# How can elements of an array be accessed by adding numbers to the array 'name', i.e the constant pointer that stores the first element's address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C, I was taught that we can access the elements of an array using pointers by incrementing the address by the memory size of data type of the array. So for an array A storing integers,

```
int *ptr = &A[0];
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
printf("%p\n", *ptr)
ptr++ // here it's +4 cause int
}
```

Would print all 3 values of array A. However, since the name of the array is a constant pointer that has the address of the array's first element, I also saw this code:

```
<information on site>

double *p;
double balance[10];

p = balance;
```

It is legal to use array names as constant pointers, and vice versa. Therefore, *(balance + 4) is a legitimate way of accessing the data at balance[4].

```
</informationonsite>
```

But how? If I add +4 to the address stored in pointer balance, if balance[] is an int array, then it's the equivalent of incrementing it, then that would make it move from pointing balance[1] to balance[2], not to balance[4]. So dereferencing (*(balance+4)) would give the value of balance[1], not [4], right? Please explain.

Comment: Kernighan & Ritchie explain this *very* well in their book "The C Programming Language". Why not treat yourself to a copy?

Comment: Have you tried it? When adding `x` to `p`, a pointer to type `T`, the new value becomes `p + x*sizeof(T)`.

Comment: "the first element of the array is a constant pointer " - Wrong. The first, second and all other elements are whatever you declare as type. Provide a [mcve]. `balance` apparently is an array. An array is **not** a pointer! As @Bathsheba: wrote: if you don't understand your tutor (or he tells nonsense), get a C book. K&R might be a good supplement, but note that it teaches mideval C, not modern C (C99, resp. C11).

Comment: @Olaf My bad, wasn't thinking when I wrote that part, meant to write the name of the array is a constant pointer.

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha: That is also wrong. Heck, why do beginners think it is called "array" if it was a pointer or "constant pointer"?

Comment: @Olaf No, it isn't..? If you declare int A[3], then A is not only the name of the array, but also the a constant pointer that stores the address of A[0], so *A == *(&A[0]). Try it out if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha The outcome is right, but your reason is wrong. Arrays can be *converted to* pointers, but arrays are *not* pointers.

Comment: @MikeCAT To use my example and to clarify this, A is 1) The name of the array and 2) The name of the constant pointer storing the address of A[0] Where does conversion of array into pointer take place?

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha C11 draft standard n1570: *6.3 Conversions 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the
unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
register storage class, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @EOF Ah, ok, and is that conversion automatic for all declared arrays at runtime, regardless of whether the converted pointer is used or not?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the standard. `A` is the array, but it is **not** a constant pointer. Don'tr confuse the automitic **conversion** of the name with the array! It does not matter **when** the conversion takes place. **Typically** there is no extra code, it is mostly a matter of semantics, i.e. type. If still unsure you shouid do some research on your own. That matter has been asked and answered here a lot of times already.

Comment: Also `(sizeof(int) == 4) && (sizeof(double) == 8)` is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the compiler knows you are pointing to a double array so: `*(x+4)` [where x is a double] is `*(double*)((char*)x + 4*sizeof(double))`

**explanation**: when using pointer of a type A then the statement `A* p = SOME_ADDRESS; p++` makes p move `sizeof(A)` bytes forward, meaning it has gone from address X to address X+sizeof(A) (in bytes)

Comment: What do you want to express by  `*balance`, please? It's a `double`.

Comment: Didn't know that, but nevertheless it still adds +8 to the address, right? But the difference between the addresses of balance[0] and balance[4] would be 32, not 8.

Comment: Hmhm, if using code to explain this, then this `(*(balance + sizeof(pointee)))` should be `(*(((char*) balance) + sizeof(pointee)))`

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha `balance[4]` is equal to `balance + (4*sizeof(double))`

Comment: @UnholySheep: Just no. It's `((char*)balance) + (4*sizeof(double))`

Comment: @alk ohh, sorry. You are completely right. trying to simplify explanations makes me write stupid things sometimes.

Comment: You example is incorrect: `*(x+4)` is `*(T*)((char*)x + 4*sizeof(T))` for `T *x`.

Comment: I CTRL+C CTRL-V that :(

Comment: @noob: You're still missing the cast back to a pointer to the original type. Otherwise you'll access the object representation through an lvalue of type `char`, which, while allowed, is probably not what you want (and definitely not equivalent to the original expression)

Comment: You might want to try this out on a compiler before posting. Currently, your code is trying to convert a `char` to a `double *`.

Comment: Aaaannnd now you're missing the cast to `double *` again. Really, *do* try out your post on a real compiler before posting. It's getting ridiculous.

Comment: will do, I'm just in a quite of a hurry now, so I try to super-fast-fix it. will look at it in a few hours again. sry :(

Comment: @noob: You could just copy my comment verbatim, but apparently that's too much effort...

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are not pointers and array names are no more pointers than arrays are. Arrays can be automatically *converted into pointers* when used in expressions except for some exceptions such as operand of unary `&` operator, `sizeof` operator, etc. Array *names* will be gone at runtime except for debugging information.

`(pointer) + (integer)` is defined to a pointer that points at `(integer)` elements after what is pointed at by `(pointer)` in [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.6 Additive operators. You don't have to think about addresses.

You cannot dereference `(*(balance+4))`, which is type `double`. `(*(balance+4))` is equivalent to `balance[4]` (see N1570 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting).

Comment: Could you explain that second paragraph a bit more? How does the pointer point to integer elements 'after' it points to addresses? Also, why don't array names exist at runtime?

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha Let me assume typical environment: The execution machine is normal computer with RAM using byte address, and addresses are used as pointers. Then, moving to `n` elements after is adding `(size of the object pointed at) * n` to the address. Array names are discarded at runtime because it isn't needed: only where in the memory the objects are matters during execution. The positions are represented as numbers (memory addresses for static objects and offset in the stack for automatic variables).